# How does current flow in a Van de Graaff generator?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential

If a Van de Graaff generator mechanically moves charge from low potential to high potential, then how does the charge actually flow onto the sphere?

I'm hearing that a spiky conductor ionizes the air, but at some point a current is flowing through the air, right? So the charge must be flowing *down* a potential gradient. I don't get how that is consistent with the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is [Gauss's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law), which says that there can be no electric field inside the upper metal sphere.

The generator uses some means to deposit electrons on the belt or chain.* The belt/chain then transports those charges up into the center of the sphere where it contacts a metal brush that is electrically connected to the upper sphere. No matter how high the voltage of the sphere (as seen from outside), Gauss's Law tells us that *inside* the sphere, *any* amount of charge on the belt/chain will seem to be a higher voltage than the interior of the sphere, and the charges will flow from the belt to the sphere.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator for more info.

---

* In an inexpensive, table-top machine, the belt ususally is charged by a [*triboelectric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) interaction with the lower roller. In larger machines, there may be a high-voltage source such as a [Cockcroft-Walton generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator) in the base to boost the efficiency of the machine.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Another question: if the spikes were in fact on the outside of the sphere, is there any chance it might still work? I'm thinking that there's a balancing of the 'electrostatic mirror charge' attraction and the normal repulsion from the charge on the sphere. (is this a broken intuition?)

Comment: And also now curious how you get the current flowing before the globe has charged. Would it be correct to say that initially (before the globe has charged) the air gets ionized due to the mirror charge on the spikes?

Comment: @MattTobias, How you "get the current flowing" is, you turn on the motor. "Current" means "moving charge." The current that charges up the top electrodes is made up of the charges that are stuck to the belt, and those charges move because the belt moves.

Comment: well yes, but the belt and the comb are air-gapped, so it doesn't seem obvious that current would initially flow across that insulating gap when the sphere has no charge on it.

I'm asking whether that initial air breakdown happens due to an induced charge on the comb/sphere, otherwise I just can't see how current would flow over that gap when you first turn the thing on. Thanks for explanation btw.